# Why my unicode is different using dump in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

Using dump method for json object in Ruby returns slightly different unicode.

I.E. payload with cyrillic symbols like this

```
payload = {'name': 'Иван'}
```

Returns following

```
puts payload.to_json.dump
{"name":"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043D"}
```

And expected unicode should be

```
{"name":"\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d"}
```

As you can see - last symbols are different, d and D.

Any way to fix this?

Also, I should mention that it happens not with all names, i.e. 'Тест' works normally.

Comment: Why does the casing matter?

Comment: I need to hash it with md5 so my sum is different because of this

Comment: Just lowercase the whole string, then.

Comment: It won't help, letter н is already in lowercase. And it returns not accurate unicode

Comment: I believe the point was that you should downcase the value `\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043D` to `\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d` to get the desired value.

Comment: Yes, exactly - lowercase *after* you dump it to JSON

Comment: I said downcase the value after after dumping it, not downcasing the keys or the original values.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working with the php server where json method encodes everything into unicode so I have to use the dump method. I've tried downcase on the dumped object and it works, so dumb and easy lol, but the php server still won't accept it. And it's funny that it works with the word 'Тест' but doesn't work with the name 'Иван'

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the php server and its' response. The way I handled the situation - I send downcased payload and downcased dumped object.